# Add 3rd party library to angular2 cli

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add a third party library to angular2, namely the Flickity slider.

Tried to install typings. When importing them I get en error that `@typings/flickity is not a module`.

Second attempt to add it in `angular-cli.json`. Added in `apps[0].scripts` as described in the docs. 
In the component i've used it like this:

this.slider = new Flickity('.news-wrapper', {
    cellAlign: 'left',
    contain: true,
    prevNextButtons: false,
    pageDots: true
  });

When compiling I get an error `Cannot find name 'Flickity'.`, but when running the site it works like a charm.

The problem is I can't build the app because of that error.

How should it be added then?

Comment: HI, I am also trying to use flickity with angular2. can you please share your success story and how u did? i am using angular cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

follow below steps to use flickity in angular-cli based project

1. npm install flickity --save
2. declare module 'flickity'; in typings.d.ts
3. import * as Flickity from "flickity"; in app.component.ts (needs to import wherever required)

use it like as you mentioned

```
this.slider = new Flickity('.news-wrapper', { cellAlign: 'left', contain: true, prevNextButtons: false, pageDots: true });
```

Comment: hi, i am new to angular 2, how can we declare module 'flickity'; in typings.d.ts??

Comment: @shajeeck add this line to typings.d.ts 
declare module 'flickity';

Comment: This solved my issue. @types/flickity was not working

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work but you can try this in the file that needs flickity.

```
let Flickity = require('flickity');
```

Just make sure you installed let Flickity using NPM