# Import libraries Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm building an Angular 2 app - I'm using the Angular quickstart as base.
I'm trying to import a library called [Flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/), but i'm not having success.

So far:
- I installed the library using `npm install flickity`
- Then i put on my `systemjs.config.js`

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '...'
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'flickity':                  'npm:flickity',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

But when i'm trying to import and USE the Flickity on my component, doesn't work:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var Flickity;

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(Flickity);
  }
}
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add 3rd party library to angular2 cli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348533/add-3rd-party-library-to-angular2-cli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`declare var Flickity;` is a way to tell TypeScript that `Flickity` is (somehow) already loaded and it's there in the scope. It won't add the library into your project.

You have to import it:

`import Flickity from 'flickity'`

Moreover, add it to your `System.config.js` so that it's clear where the library main JS file is:

```
flickity: {
  defaultExtension: 'js',
  main: './dist/flickity.pkgd.js'
}
```